# trying to recreate getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, dom

```
function getElementsByClassName(cls) {
  const result = [];
  const checkClass = (element) => {
    const children = element.children;
    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      if()
        if (children[i].contains(cls)) {
          result.push(children[i]); 
        }
      if (children[i].hasChildNodes()) {
     
        checkClass(children[i]);      }
    }
  };
  checkClass(document.body); 
  return result;
}
```

Hello, all.

From what I understand childNodes has undefined nodes like "text" that can't go through .contain method.

So I switched from childNodes to children and then I am still getting the same ERROR message as below.

```
getElementsByClassName("targetClassName")

VM1349:8 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at checkClass (<anonymous>:8:23)
    at getElementsByClassName (<anonymous>:18:3)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

I understand issue has to do with while iterating through the node list and then trying to apply contains, but I just don't get why it won't execute it after switching it to elements rather than nodes.

Please advise.

Comment: This can't be your real code, since `if()` is a syntax error.

Comment: The entity one wants to process does not expose a `contains` property but has to feature a `className` and/or a `classList` property, the latter than can be looked up with its `contains` method

Comment: how about querying every of a document's element via `document.getElementsByTagName('*')`? Or is your approach more about recreating `getElementsByTagName` itself?

Comment: @PeterSeliger - I think it's about recreating `getElementsByClassName` (not tag name), probably as a learning exercise.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ... but then it was almost a no-brainer since the base collection easily can be queried via `document.getElementsByTagName('*')`.

Comment: @PeterSeliger - True, you could take that approach to it. I assume this is a learning exercise, so whether you use that approach or some other approach depends on the point of the learning exercise. :-)

Answer (score 3):

> From what I understand childNodes has undefined nodes like "text" that can't go through .contain method.

I don't know what you mean by "undefined nodes," but Text nodes are perfectly valid arguments for `contains`:

```js
const div = document.getElementById("x");
const text = div.firstChild;
console.log(text.nodeName);      // #text
console.log(div.contains(text)); // true
```

```html
<div id="x">foo</div>
```

That said, using `children` in your function is reasonable, since only Elements can have classes and your code doesn't need to work on document fragments (e.g., checking their contents), so you only need to look at Elements, not other kinds of nodes.

I assume it's this code:

```
if (children[i].contains(cls)) {
```

that gives you

> parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

`cls` in your code is a **string**, not a Node. As the error says, `contains` accepts **Nodes**. It doesn't accept strings.

---

A couple of side notes:

1. Properly recreating [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) in your own code is fairly complicated, because it returns a **live** `HTMLCollection`, not a snapshot `NodeList` like `querySelectorAll` does. That means properly recreating it would require using a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to track changes over time and update the list you return as things change. But to recreate it without that "live" feature, you'll probably want a recursive function.
2. `getElementsByClassName` accepts **multiple** class names, not just one, in a space-delimited string.
3. It works on the **entire** document, not just `body` (elements in `head` can have classes).

FWIW, a non-live solution's general form might look something like this:

```
function getElementsByClassName(cls) {
    const classes = cls.split(" ");
    return worker(document.documentElement, classes, []);
}

function worker(element, classes, result) {
    if (/*element has all the classes*/) {
        result.push(element);
    }
    for /*...loop through `children`...*/ {
        worker(child, classes, result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Or**, as [Peter Seliger points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63502181/trying-to-recreate-getelementsbyclassname?noredirect=1#comment112290992_63502181), you could start with the `HTMLCollection` from [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) and just filter it. I assume this is a learning exercise, so it depends on the purpose of the learning exercise.

Comment: I bet more on that OP got confused about `elm.contains` versus `elm.classList.contains`.

Comment: @PeterSeliger - Oooh, that seems likely.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I finally was able to figure out that by  adding a classList to (children[i].classList.contains(cls)), i was able to get it working. Though there seems to be another glitch... I am trying to figure out what I should be implementing. As you have mentioned, recursion is another way but I just don't understand how base case can be set for infinitely looping through children.

Comment: @paul.kim1901 - Notice how each call to `worker` passes in a different element, working from the `documentElement`, to its first child, to *that* child's first child, etc. Eventually you run out of descendant elements (you find one that has no children) on that branch and move to the next branch, then the next. Eventually you run out of branches (children of `documentElement` and their descendants) and you're done. E.g., running out of nodes is the base case.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// ... non live collection approach ...
//
// - does not "know" `String.prototype.trim`,
// - is unaware of `Array.prototype.includes` ...
// - ... as well as of `Element.prototype.classList`
//
function getElementsByClassName(node, className) {

  const regXSplitWS = (/\s+/);
  const regXTrimLeft = (/^\s+/);
  const regXTrimRight = (/\s+$/);

  function trim(str) {
    return str.replace(regXTrimLeft, '').replace(regXTrimRight, '');
  }
  function getClassList(str) {
    str = trim(String(str || ''));
    return (
      (!str && []) ||
      str.split(regXSplitWS)
    );
  }
  const classList = getClassList(className);

  function doesMatchClassNameQuery(elmClassList) {
    return (
      !!elmClassList.length &&
      !!classList.length &&
      classList.every(function (queryName) {
        return (elmClassList.indexOf(queryName) >= 0);
      })
    );   
  }

  function query(collector, elm/*, idx, collection*/) {
    if (doesMatchClassNameQuery(getClassList(elm.className))) {

      collector.push(elm);
    }
    // query recursively.
    return collector.concat(Array.from(elm.children).reduce(query, []));
  }
  // start querying.
  return Array.from((node && node.children) || []).reduce(query, []);
}


console.log(
  document.body.getElementsByClassName('baz bizz')
);
console.log(
  getElementsByClassName(document.body, 'baz bizz')
);

console.log(
  document.body.getElementsByClassName('foo')
);
console.log(
  getElementsByClassName(document.body, 'foo')
);

console.log(getElementsByClassName());
console.log(getElementsByClassName(null, 'bar'));

console.log(getElementsByClassName(document.body));
console.log(document.body.getElementsByClassName(''));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="level-1 foo">
  <div class="level-2a bar">
    <div class="level-3a baz bizz" />
    <div class="level-3b buzz " />
  <div>
  <div class="level-2b baz">
    <div class="level-3c bizz buzz" />
    <div class="level-3d foo bar" />
  <div>
  <div class="level-2c bizz buzz">
    <div class="level-3e foo bar" />
    <div class="level-3f baz bizz" />
  <div>
<div>
```